# FFMpeg C++ How to create a filter with multiple outputs?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

For example, we have one `AVFrame` with a size of  128x128 pixels and the task is to split the `AVFrame` into 4 parts (4 separate `AVFrame`). To do this, I fill the graph with filters using the `avfilter_graph_parse2(...)` function, and then call `avfilter_graph_config(...)`.

Let's start. Let's cut out the top left corner. To crop a frame, we need to use the `crop` filter, which means we initialize the AVFilterGraph graph with the line:

```
buffer = width = 128: height = 128: pix_fmt = 2: time_base = 1/25, pixel_aspect = 128/64 [pad_in];
[pad_in] crop = w = 64: h = 64: x = 0: y = 0, buffersink;
```

Everything works great! Now let's try to make several outputs:

```
buffer = width = 128: height = 128: pix_fmt = 2: time_base = 1/25, pixel_aspect = 128/64 [pad_in];
[pad_in] crop = w = 64: h = 64: x = 0: y = 0, buffersink;
[pad_in] crop = w = 64: h = 64: x = 64: y = 0, buffersink;
[pad_in] crop = w = 64: h = 64: x = 0: y = 64, buffersink;
[pad_in] crop = w = 64: h = 64: x = 64: y = 64, buffersink
```

As you can see, we have one `buffer` for the input image, 4 `crop` filters for cutting each piece, and 4 `buffersink` filters for the output images. The call `avfilter_graph_parse2(...)` returns 0, which is good, but `avfilter_graph_config()` returns the error code `-22 == AVERROR(EINVAL)` and the message is output to the console: `Input pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "Parsed_crop_3" of crop not connected to any source.`

I am asking for your help in creating a filter with multiple outputs.

Comment: [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, thanks for your comment. Before that, I only looked about video filters, so I did not see `split`. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

[Alan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841744/ffmpeg-c-how-to-create-a-filter-with-multiple-outputs?noredirect=1#comment112893492_63841744) directed me to [`split` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit). And I did this:

```
buffer=width=128:height=128:pix_fmt=2:time_base=1/25,sar=1 [pad_in];
[pad_in] split=4 [pad_split_0] [pad_split_1] [pad_split_2] [pad_split_3];
[pad_split_0] crop=w=64:h=64:x=0:y=0,buffersink;
[pad_split_1] crop=w=64:h=64:x=64:y=0,buffersink;
[pad_split_2] crop=w=64:h=64:x=0:y=64,buffersink;
[pad_split_3] crop=w=64:h=64:x=64:y=64,buffersink
```